# Group by named column

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I always forget how to do things like this.

I have a database table with birthdates and I want to find out how many people have the same age.

I'm trying:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF( YEAR, birthdate, CURDATE( ) ) AS age, COUNT( age ) 
FROM  person 
GROUP BY age
```

but get the error

> Unknown column 'age' in 'field list'

How can I do a group by on a named column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aliases can't be used in group by clauses, nor can it be used in other columns in the select list (yes, this sucks).

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF( YEAR, birthdate, CURDATE( ) ) AS age, COUNT( TIMESTAMPDIFF( YEAR, birthdate, CURDATE( ) ))
FROM  person
GROUP BY TIMESTAMPDIFF( YEAR, birthdate, CURDATE( ) )
```

Comment: This is one of those things that every developer wished would work how you think it should. I don't understand why it doesn't work... I can't imagine it would cause any real problems...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Yes, this part of MySQL is frustrating when it doesn't work like you think it would.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out.

Ok, I need to use `COUNT(*)`

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF( YEAR, birthdate, CURDATE( ) ) AS age, COUNT( * ) 
FROM  person 
GROUP BY age
```